# Allow users to edit files in a folder but not create new ones

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, permissions, ntfs, domain

I am trying to restrict file creation in a particular NTFS shared folder containing .xlsx files.
We need users to be able to still edit and save the existing files.

So far, I have tried setting permissions for the group in the following configuration: [Files Only Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ8Rc.png) and [This Folder Only Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZUit.png) and now when I attempt to open a .xlsx file i get a prompt saying the files is locked by [User who users the file]. I normally see this when a user has the file open but this is a test folder with only admin permission.

I greatly appreciate any help and thank you!

Comment: To my knowledge there is no NTFS that would allow editing of files but prevent them from being created.

Comment: After running into this issue I did some research and found this article; https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/a-basic-introduction-to-ntfs-permissions.html which seems to indicate some permissions behaviors are different based on if it is for files or folders. My understanding was a permission for Create Files/Write Data on a folder would only effect the creation of files.

Comment: I suppose you can give individual write permissions to specific files and remove the permissions from the parent folder.  The problem is I suspect the minute you save the file, once after changing the files, it will inherit the permissions of the folder.

Comment: I had disabled inheritance from the parent folder to the folder containing the files. I think assigning permissions per file/user might work! I'll give that a try.

Comment: I feel like your permission request is a bit contradictory.